# maven dependencies and licensing

Tags: maven, dependencies

Is there any rule which says transitive dependencies in maven will be at same license agreement as of the main one.
For eg. if I have a direct dependency on A which ships B & C transitively. A being on LGPL, can this be inferred that both B & C are at LGPL? I can sense this with LGPL definition but is there any rule which says this.

Answer (score 2):

Maven does not actively concern itself with these licenses, so in terms of a rule that is enforced by the tool: *no, such does not exist*.

[This other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6640173/how-do-you-manage-the-licenses-of-the-dependencies-libraries-of-your-project) describes solutions inside your internal repository as well as a link to the [Maven License Validator Plugin](http://code.google.com/p/maven-license-validator-plugin/), however, the latter is either "done" or abandoned.

You could also use the [Maven License Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/license-maven-plugin/) and somehow automatically evaluate its output -- assert when seeing unwanted license types.